# paper rejected because not so general

Tags: graph-theory

Dear All,

thanks in advance to anyone that could give some suggestion.

Here's the situation: starting from a type of random graph I extend
the construction introducing a new class of random graphs. I studied
some properties and I write a paper that I submitted to the arxiv.org
successfully after the endorsment of one of the author cited in the
references. I have a math degree but I don't have any formal
affiliation to my university, so I submitted the paper as a private
without affiliation.

After some minor review I consider submitting it to a math journal. I
submitted it and after one month my paper was refused because of the
following reviewer motivation:

"The paper considers random graphs where roughly speaking one starts
with a precise graph and adds new vertices into random cycles.
Clearly, the graphs that are obtained have a very special form. The
presented results are neither interesting nor significant enough for
publication in our journal."

So it seems to me that even if the paper was correct it's not as
general results as required.

So here are my questions:

Considering that the paper seems ok, I mean no first read bad mistakes, would I submit it to another journal and see if is accepted?

In case I would try to generalize the process and would I have to
submit again to the same journal?

If I don't have any affiliation this could be somehow bad at the eyes
of a reviewer?

Thanks to everyone that could help.

Paolo

Comment: This question is too specific to your circumstances - MathOverflow is not a place to ask people to look at your results and tell you if the reviewer's assessment is correct or not, so I have voted to close.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you added a link to your paper in the Arxiv.

Generally speaking, if a paper is rejected on the basis of not being interesting or significant to the level of the submitted journal, you can always try with a lower-category journal. 

I would only resubmit to the same journal if the paper is rejected for (1) the referee incorrectly believing that there is a mathematical flaw in the proofs (2) the referee points out a specific flaw in the proofs that I'm able to fix in a short time.

Comment: Zev, I don't think he is asking anyone to look at his results.  He is hoping based on the reviewers comment if that is sufficient to not resubmit the paper as is to another journal.  I think your vote to close should not be based on what you have stated in your comment.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: Seconding Gerhard's comment, and hence casting a vote *against* closing. It seems that the question is really about protocol, procedure and expected behaviour, not so much about the particular results.

Comment: I see that votes to close are continuing to come in without Yemon's vote to keep open having been declared canceled. Please follow the rules, everyone!

Comment: You raised this question on the Usenet newsgroup sci.math, and it appears you have learned nothing from the answers posted there. Anyone interested in seeing the earlier discussion can search Google groups for "not so general". 

Comment: I am surprised at the reason chosen for closing; history on other forums is a poor reason for closing, while history on THIS forum is not so poor areason.  I believe the community could benefit from one or two additional comments from the closers, or at the very least voting up Gerry Myerson's comment above.  I also think this is another example to add to a meta thread on protocols for closing MathOverflow questions.  I invite additional comment, either here or on a meta thread.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5264

Comment: Gerhard- I tried to rewrite the question into something likely to be reopened, and I didn't have much luck.  When you strip out the details, the question is basically just "if my paper gets rejected by one journal, should I submit to another journal, or should I try to make it better?" which is just not a question for MathOverflow, since it doesn't have a clear answer in general.  

Comment: I agree that "subjective and argumentative" was probably not the right choice of reason for closing, but take that up with J.C. Ottem; "doesn't admit a precise answer" isn't one of the listed reasons, and we can't change that for the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Ben. I think you are stripping too much when you say what the basic question is, but I won't improve on your rewrite attempts. If JC had enlightened us about his choice with a comment, that would have been good protocol and probably shut me up.  The reasons for closing still don't seem great to me. but it looks less arbitrary and a little more thoughtful now.  Thanks again.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: One minor comment: JC Ottem might not have had a choice when it comes to the reason for closing.  If three of the previous people had chosen "subjective and argumentative" then it wouldn't matter what JC chose.  It is the _majority_ decision that is displayed, not the last one.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need a second (and perhaps third) opinion from a professional.  If possible, write some individual emails requesting people to give a quick impression as to the publication-worthiness of your result.  Since the result is on ArXiv, no question of precedence should arise.  You can ask the author you asked before for names of other people to ask.  It is important that you emphasize that you don't need them to spend time going over the paper (if all you need is a quick impression; for a more thorough review, you will want a different strategy of approach).

Please note: MathOverflow is a place for specific questions.  If you have trouble with a particular proof, you can ask about that detail.  Zev Chonoles is right in commenting that MathOverflow is not a place to solicit reviewers for your work.  Pablo Shmerkin is (somewhat) right in the idea that it is smart to include a link to your ArXiv submission, in case someone is interested and volunteers to review it.  (In short: Asking for review on MathOverflow, bad; making it possible using less than 100 characters without asking, not so bad, and possibly priceless.)

Gerhard "Will Rewrite Commercials For Barter" Paseman, 2011.02.27

Comment: I want to add that making it possible on MathOverflow for people to get at your results also gets a number of eager non-professionals, who might be willing to help.  Referee practice for people who will enter the profession, more eyes debugging your work; how could it not be a win-win, especially if everyone involved volunteered?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.02.27